# Cannot raise Complex Int to power

Tags: haskell, types, casting, complex-numbers

It seems that raising a `Complex Int` to a power violates some contract in its instances. Am I wrong on this?

minimal example below

```
compl :: Complex Int -> Maybe (Complex Int)
compl d = (d^) <$> Just 3
```

And the error message:

```
No instance for (RealFloat Int) arising from an operator section
      In the first argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘(d ^)’
      In the expression: (d ^) <$> Just 3
      In an equation for ‘compl’: compl d = (d ^) <$> Just 3
```

Is there any way around this? Allowing this type to be a float doesn't make any sense in my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(^)` is a method of `Num`.  [The `Complex` type's instantiation of `Num`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch17.html#x25-21800017) is declared as:

```
instance RealFloat a => Num (Complex a)
```

That is, you can't treat a `Complex a` as a `Num` unless `a` is a `RealFloat`, which an `Int` is not.  Use `Complex Double` or the like instead.

Comment: Now you might ask why not `instance Num a => Num (Complex a)`?  The answer is that `abs x` and `signum x` as defined for complex numbers use the magnitude of `x` which requires `sqrt` from the `RealFloat` instance.  E.g. `abs (1 :+ 2)` = `sqrt 5` which is not an integer.